# How to update QSqlTableModel after database connection has been changed changed

Tags: c++, database, qt, model-view, qabstracttablemodel

I have class which is derived from `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.
I use SQLite database.
And I need to change database file.
I close old database file, call SetDatabaseName("path to new file") and open new database file.
Now I just call select() for the model, but it returns false.
And if I call setTable("table") and only after that select(), everything works...
But name of the table is the same...

I didn't find any method which allows to inform a model that database connection has been changed....
Do you know a better way to inform the model?

---

Ok. I have returned to this topic once again.

After db is changed I have to call setTable() with the same table name to reinit table model.
And I did not find a better way how to reinit table view, co I call

```
pTableView->setModel(NULL);
pTableView->setModel(model);
```

This generates a lot of unnecessary code calls, but in other case table view does not know about changes in table model (for example columns count).

I did not find a better way to reinitialize `QSqlTableModel` and `QTableView`. Some ideas?

Comment: And I have another problem...
Is it possible to create and set up (set table name...) QSqlTableModel before database is opened?

Now I receive error, that table "table" is not found even if it exists in the database...

Answer (score 2):

```
// create your model(parent=0, QSqlDatabase::database());
// set your table model->setTable("tablename");
tableview->setModel(this->model)
bool ok = model->select() // model should populate itself and refresh tableView as well
```

Answer (score 0):

That was my fault :(
With help of sources I found in which cases select() returns false.
And one fieldname in the table of my new database misses one letter:( So, QSqlQuery with select returned error.
setTable call updates fieldnames of the table, so select returns true.